# Problema con el Inicio de sesion en .net usando mvc? (no me valida ni me reconoce las credenciales)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo creada la vista y el controlador del login pero no me valida ni me redirige a las tablas, en este caso a la de Cursos una vez logueado, es más, ni me valida si tiene datos o no, muestro el código del controlador

```
public class InicioController : Controller
{
    // GET: Inicio
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult Index(Inicio model)
    {
        ColegioConnection modeloBD = new ColegioConnection();
        var usuario = modeloBD.Inicios.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Usuario == model.Usuario && x.Contraseña == model.Contraseña);

        if (usuario== null)
        {
            ViewBag.Mensaje = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos";
            return View();
        }

        // se asigna el nombre del usuario que inicia sesion
        Session["Contraseña"] = usuario.Contraseña;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}


<--ahora el de la vista del controlador: -->

@model Modelo.BaseDatos.Inicio

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Inicio";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Inicio", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Inicie Sesion</legend>

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
            <div style="border: 1px solid red">
                @ViewBag.Message
            </div>
        }
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(a => a.Usuario)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.Usuario)</td>
                <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Usuario)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.Contraseña)
                </td>

                <td>
                    @Html.PasswordFor(a => a.Contraseña)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Contraseña)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="Inicio" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
}
```

PD2: la página web la hice con capas, por lo tanto estoy trayendo la Base de Datos desde una biblioteca de clases llamada `Modelo.BaseDatos ('Using Modelo.BaseDatos')`

Lo que quiero es que me valide las credenciales que creé en la tabla para que me valide en el inicio, y si es lo contrario que no me deje entrar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Amigo no has considerado utilizar Identity? Puesto que te veo tratando de reinventar la rueda.

Comment: es que quiero entender la logica de como funciona un login y en cuanto a sus validaciones, al igual que el crud que hice con las tablas no fue el que saca entity framework.

Comment: Por eso mismo amigo la mejor forma de entender es mirando un ejemplo práctico  que funciona. Crea otro proyecto con autenticación que utilice Identity y fijate en el cod de AccountController, a simple vista verás que te faltan cosas, como son: pasar la ruta de donde estabas como parámetro para luego de autenticarte redirigirte a esa ruta